# making the passed parameters provided in URL as optional [Non-Capturing] using " ?: "

Tags: regex, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am tying to make the passed parameters in the URL as optional. I have a URL like this ->

```
path('users/<optional_value>',views.users_list_or_detail, name='users_list_or_details'),
```

I do not want to make 2 different URLS to give me the list or the detail. How can I make the second `<optional_value>` as optional so that if by any means, I am not providing the `<optional_value>` to the view, it gives me a list of users and user details if provided?

one option I have looked over on Internet is

```
http://localhost:8000/users/?from=user_id
```

How can I make it optional using the **?:** in the `urls.py` given in the Django's documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Within your template (this will create the url as you've defined it)

```
<a href="{% url 'users_list_or_details' %}?from=user_id ">Link</a>
```

Within your view

```
if 'from' in request.kwargs:
    user_id = from
```

Comment: Thanks HenryM. Thank you agai for helping me out. I have your answer saved. This is my second question on this. Your method works very fine last time but I just want to learn that **?:**  method.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, provide a default argument `None` for your url kwargs, `optional_value` in this case and check if parameter is available or not.

Something like:

```
def users_list_or_detail(request, optional_value=None):
    if optional_value:
        # render detail
    else:
        # render list
```

Comment: but it'll throw an error saying **looking for second <optional> argument, not provided** if I hit the URL without the ```<optional_param>```

Comment: @Deshwal did you try this approach?

Comment: Yes. I hit on the URL like ```users/``` and the error was that the url needs an extra argument. What would I be doing wrong?